# ¿Cuál es el significado de este script?

Tags: javascript, html, script

Esta es la segunda pregunta que posteo en este foro u seguramente no sea la ultima...
La razón de esto es que mi profesor de informática nunca explica nada.

En el último problema que nos dio en JavaScript aparecía este script el cual no se como interpretarlo, si alguien sabe que me diga porfavor.

```
function escriu10 (element){var i; resultat6.innerhtml=""; for (i=1;i<=i++){ resultat6.innerhtml+=elem.value + " "+ i +"<br/>"
```

Comment: ¿ Lo has ejecutado en un navegador ? ¿ Que has observado en dicha ejecución ?

Comment: Para que la pregunta tenga mejor recepción se mas explicativa en tu pregunta. Con interpretarlo te refieres a donde ejecutarlo? o te refieres a una explicación de lo que la función realiza?

Comment: Saludos. El código que pones está incompleto; le hace falta al menos un ' ;', y dos `}'. Lo cual hace suponer esta incompleto. Te comento adicionalmente (si te dedicaras a programación) no encontraras documentación que te indique línea a línea que se hace en el código, seguro encontraras código documentado por función o ciertas parte muy complejas, pero tendrás código que deberás "leer" para entender que se hace.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor consulta [ask]. Tu pregunta no se ajusta al formato del sitio y posíblemente sea cerrada. Consulta [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript) y **crea un marcador para regresar con frecuencia a esa página** de documentación.

Answer (score 0):

```
` 
function escriu10(element){
var resultat6 = document.getElementById("re");
var i; 
resultat6.innerhtml="";
for (i=1;i<=element.lenght;i++){ 
resultat6.innerhtml+=elem.value + " " + i +"<br/>"}
}`
```

Para que medio funcione ese código sin errores debes cerrar la funcion y el ciclo for tambien con: }. Tambien debes declarar un div con un id en html y guardarlo en una variable. ademas en el ciclo for te falta un punto y coma ; recuerda que el ciclo for se compone de tres estados así for (i;i<a.length;i++){}. fijate que aquí hay 2 punto y coma.